# Poll utilisation for blocking

Tags: c

How to block `poll` so that it gets activated only when we press a keyboard button.

Because is continues alone without event.

I have read all the manual for that.

```
 while(i<5){  
      struct pollfd fds[2];
    int timeout_msecs = 500;
    int ret;
      fds[0].fd=STDIN_FILENO;
      fds[0].events=POLLIN | POLLWRBAND | POLLHUP;

    ret = poll(fds, 2, -1);
    snprintf(buffer, 12,"%d",ret);

    //write_raw(7,i,"z",1);

              if(ret > 0) {
              //  write_raw(3,i,"a",1);

                 if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN) {
                   // write_raw(4,i,"b",1);
        //      write_raw(3,1,buffer,1);

        posx=posx-1;
              write_raw(posy,posx,"_|_",3);

              sleep(5);
              fds[0].events = POLLHUP;
                 }
                  if(fds[0].revents & POLLHUP){

              write_raw(4,i,"a",1);

                 }
              }

             fds[0].events=NULL; 
              i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please add a little example code to clarify your question, it is incomprehensible as it stands

Answer (score 0):

You only have 1 file descriptor that you want to monitor for events, but you're telling poll() you have 2. You need to do

```
 ret = poll(fds, 1, -1);
```

You have no use for getting an event when you can write urgent data to stdin (whatever that would mean, so

```
  fds[0].events=POLLIN | POLLHUP;
```

This makes no sense

```
 fds[0].events=NULL;
```

Remove that line.

Your next issue is that you register for read events. But you never read any input on stdin. If there's data available, you will get an event every time, until you actually read all the available data.

Your question states that you want to get keyboard events, you get that by reading data, but your code mostly have calls to a write_raw() function, which sounds like it writes data instead of reading data.

Comment: @Ramj Then you need to debug what's going on. Figure out what poll() returns. Figure out which events are returned in `fds[0].revents`. You also would get much better help if you tell us what you do, what is happening, and what you expect to happen.

Comment: Checking what error you get if `poll()` returns `-1` would be a good start. If you deliberately fail to check for errors, you aren't really entitled to be surprised when your code doesn't work as expected.